# Apache - Redirect traffic from alias to port

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite

iHello everyone,
I'm in trouble with mod_rewrite in apache2

i'm trying to redirect all traffic incoming on localhost/music to localhost:8080, i've read a lot on apache documentation but i could not find a working example (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

And no, i'm not trying to redirect traffic to tomcat (so i imagine i can't use mod_jk), i just want to see on alias /music my other app running on port 8080, it's a web stream music player called CherryMusic that is written in python and runs with html5.

I'm on debian server (precisely running raspbian on a raspberry pi)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

in the following example, if your request to /music/(example.mp3) it will redirected with http status 302 to  http://localhost:8080/example.mp3

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/music/(.*)         http://localhost:8080/$1 [L,R=302]
```

In the above example the browser will be redirected to http://localhost:8080/example.mp3 (will work only for you cause it redirected to localhost)

if you are looking to proxy the request -  the web server will connect to localhost:8080 , than you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/music/(.*)         http://localhost:8080/$1 [L,P]
```